# Can I make my dough for dinner rolls ahead in bread maker and refrigerate overnight?

Tags: dough

I want to make my dough for dinner rolls tonight in my bread maker and bake in the morning. Will this work? Also do I cut and shape before putting in the fridge for the night or do I do this in the morning before baking?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can refrigerate after the machine has kneaded the dough. Cover the bowl tightly. In the morning, take the dough out of the fridge and let it 'wake up' in a warm place for an hour, cut and shape, then either prove them again or bake straight away (a second prove will give you a lighter texture).